# iOS 8 Webapp Status Bar overlapping webapp header in homescreen mode

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, ios8, meta-tags

I have a jquery mobile & php webapp that is working correctly in iOS7. I recently upgraded to iOS8 to do some testing and I have an issue with the status bar now overlapping the header of the webapp. This also seems to be causing my image upload within the webapp to break the layout once its completed.

EDIT: This issue only happens when the ipad is opened in landscape mode. In portrait mode it works correctly and displays the status bar, then my file upload works correctly. Tested in 8.0.x and 8.1 iPad.

Does anyone have any ideas?

iOS7
[image: iOS7]

iOS8
[image: iOS8]

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png" /> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon.png"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/grid.css">

    <script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/jqm1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/bespokeValidateRules.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jqm1.4.4/jquery.mobile.external-png-1.4.4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jqm1.4.4/jquery.mobile.inline-png-1.4.4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jqm1.4.4/jquery.mobile.inline-svg-1.4.4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jqm1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jqm1.4.4/Theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jqm1.4.4/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jqm1.4.4/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.4.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/responsiveGrid.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css"> 

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="a" >
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" style="min-height: 40px;">

         <div class="ui-grid-b" >
           <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="margin-left: 28px; "><h5 style='font-size:9pt;'></h5></div></div>
           <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a"  style="text-align: center; "><h1>My App</h1></div></div>
           <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="margin-right: 28px; text-align: right; "><h5 style='font-size:9pt'></h5></div></div>
        </div>
   </div><!-- /header -->
     <div data-role="content">
    <a href="#" id='networkLost' class="ui-btn">Button!!</a>
    </div><!-- /content -->
  </div><!-- /page -->
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in iOS 8.3.

Answer (score 0):

Seems fixed on iOS 8.1.

[UPDATE: Fixed on iPhone only, iPad is still experiencing the problem.]

On 8.0.X you can use

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
```

as it appears to use "black-translucent" behavior even using "default" value.

For more information about the available values: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

Comment: I just installed 8.1 and this is not fixed. The problem only happens when the web app is opened in landscape view. Any other ideas?

Comment: I didn't notice you were trying on an iPad. The issue is fixed with iOS 8.1 on iPhone (5 at least), but I had a chance to test on an iPad and even if it changed a little bit the behavior the problem is still there.

Comment: Ive also noticed that if I leave my webapp open and the screen locks, when I unlock the screen although the app is still up nothing will work on it.. links etc. Have you noticed this?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. There are issues with timing functions after lock/wait, here is some reference: http://www.sencha.com/blog/apple-shows-love-for-html5-with-ios-8 (in The Bugs section) and here http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5895945212395520 . Also, I experienced problems with Iframes touch events in standalone apps, as reported here http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios8-iphone6-web-developers-designers in Bugs and Problems: "Touch events inside iframes on home-screen apps are not being reported"

Comment: Hi - thanks these links are useful! Do you have any ideas of workarounds for these issues or whether there will be a new ios release with a fix?